# Function composition of form f(x)(g(x)) using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I can't figure out a transform for `f(x)(g(x))` using the functions available in Ramda. I'm hoping for something like `R.something(f, g)(x)` ideally - just so long as `x` only appears once and is the final argument.

`f` is a function taking `x` that returns a function

`g` is a function taking `x` that returns a value

I've tried `pipe`,`compose`,`chain`, but tbh I'm guessing pretty hard and no one of them work. I recently asked a similar question and I'd love to know a resource with loads of useful identities if one exists so I don't need to keep asking on SO :)

Comment: Btw, if you consider `constant = x => y => x` this is an applicative functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chain` was close: it does `chain(f, g)(x) == f(g(x))(x)` on functions. So you just need to flip `f` before passing it into `chain`:

```
R.chain(R.flip(f), g)(x)
```

or

```
const something = R.compose(R.chain, R.flip)
something(f, g)(x)
```

Comment: I just realised this myself! Thanks

Comment: Let's call it `ap`.

Comment: @ftor Oh. I realised that  `R.chain` is Haskell's `=<<`, but given that everything is flipped I didn't think there's an equivalent to `(=<<) . flip`. You definitely should post [that](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) as an answer.

Comment: @ftor please add that as full answer :)